# left outer join in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

like.....

vehicle table

id vehicle_id vehicle_Name
1   TN10001     car
2    TN100       bus
3    tn4oo       van

device table

id device_ID .... Vehicle_id
1   d1...           1
2   d2 ...               null

i want vehicleid's(tn100,tn4oo) from vehicle table which r not in device table( have vehicle id Tn10001 )

where bi directional one to many mapping is mapped in vehicle.

Comment: I do not understand how/where/what you want the left outer join? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want vehicle_id's from vehicle table which are not in device table....

Comment: What is the final SQL you expect?

Comment: How are you querying the domain? HQL, Criteria, QueryOver, LINQ-NH...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var invalidVehicleIds= DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Device))
.SetProjection(Projections.Id());

Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Vehicle))
.Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("Id",invalidVehicleIds))
.List<Vehicle>()
```